# Calling functions within SimPy processes

Tags: python, simpy

I am trying to write a program for process communication using Python and SimPy. If I put all code in a single function and call

```
simpy.Environment().process(function_one())
```

everything runs perfectly. However, if I call another function within function_one() like

```
def function_one(self):
  function_two()
```

function_two will never be executed. function_two will be executed if I call it like this

```
def function_one(self):
  simpy.Environment().process(function_two())
```

However, the rest of function_one will then executed and won't wait for function_two to execute. I obviously don't want to put all of my code in one function so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Functions passed to `process()` have to be generator functions yielding event instances. Furthermore, you have to call `Environment.run()` in order to actually execute the simulation. You should read the [tutorial](http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/simpy_intro/index.html) to get started with SimPy.